# Trying to find alternative Regex for the following - Non multi-line

Tags: regex

Is there a way to get this regex but not with multi-line?

```
(\d\.\d)(?=\D|$)
```

Relatively new to Regex and can't seem to work it out!

Thanks a lot!
Liam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the $ can be replaced with \Z to achieve the "End of String" instead of "End of string or End of Line"

so the resultant expression would be

```
(\d\.\d)(?=\D|\Z)
```